# MongoDB - How do I update many arrays of a single document in a single operation? Is it possible?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a large file full of repetitive `$push` operations that I'd like to simplify. My current solution works fine and looks like this:

```
seshID = '1234'
seshDate = '3/30/2021'
seshTimestamp = '1:00 PM'
seshDuration = 60
seshEfficiency = 75
seshAbility = 80

users.update_one({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.date': seshDate}})
users.update_one({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.timestamp': seshTimestamp}})
users.update_one({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.duration': seshDuration}})
users.update_one({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.efficiency': seshEfficiency}})
users.update_one({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.ability': seshAbility}})
```

In my actual working file, there are many, many more fields and arrays, so it's starting to get ugly and hard to manage, but at least it works so far.

I want to use a single `update` operation to do this same task, just for readability. I don't know enough about Pymongo or MongoDB to know if this is doable or what operation to use. I hope someone can offer solutions. This is what I've tried (plus other similar methods), but no luck so far:

```
users.update({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {{'sessionsLog.date': seshDate},
               {'sessionsLog.timestamp': seshTimestamp},
               {'sessionsLog.duration': seshDuration},
               {'sessionsLog.efficiency': seshEfficiency},
               {'sessionsLog.ability': seshAbility}}
    })
```

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Use proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the syntax almost right, try:

```
users.update({'userID': seshID},
    {'$push': {'sessionsLog.date': seshDate,
               'sessionsLog.timestamp': seshTimestamp,
               'sessionsLog.duration': seshDuration,
               'sessionsLog.efficiency': seshEfficiency,
               'sessionsLog.ability': seshAbility}
    })
```